# Integrate the following differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the D.E. $$\dfrac{du}{dv} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\frac{u+v}{u}\right)^{2}$$
How could I get the implicit equation of $u$ and $v$.

This question came from the final part of solving a differential equation.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: *deferential* is a very nice lapsus linguae !

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{du}{dv} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\frac{u+v}{u}\right)^{2}$$
Substitute $u=tv \implies u'=t+vt'$
$$t+t'v = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{2}$$It's separable.